# How to set multiple options at once for a field with parsley in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I went through the parsley.js documentation and I didn't understand how (or even whether it's possible or not) to configure multiple options in block in javascript. For example, I have this select field:

```
<select
    data-parsley-error-message="Error message"
    id="continent"
    class="js-continent-select">

    <option value="">option 1</option>
    <option value="">option 2</option>
</select>
```

In javascript I manage to do this:

```
$("#continent").parsley().addConstraint('required');
$("#continent").parsley().options.classHandler = '.js-continent-select';
$("#continent").parsley().options.errorsContainer = '.continent-error-container';
```

And it works, but I would rather do something like this:

```
$("#continent").parsley().options = {
    errorsContainer: '.continent-error-container' 
    required: true, 
    classHandler: '.js-continent-select'
};
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If your field is already bound, then change the options directly (but don't replace the object itself):

```
$.extend($("#continent").parsley().options, {
    errorsContainer: '.continent-error-container',
    required: true, 
    classHandler: '.js-continent-select'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$("#continent").parsley({
    errorsContainer: '.continent-error-container',
    required: true, 
    classHandler: '.js-continent-select'
});
```

(Source: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-usage-configuration)

Comment: no, it doesn't work, I've already tried it. Just to be sure, I even tried setting only one option this way: 1) $("#continent").parsley({required: true}); 2) $("#continent").parsley().options.required = true;
The first has no effect while the second works